# Add a "Username History" to the profile field

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, display-names

While users may (and do) exercise their right to change their profile display name would it be useful to have a "Username History" or "Formerly known as" section in the profile. This could show the most recent (or two or three) most recent usernames of the user.

I know it's a fairly trivial idea but if a user changes the name and avatar I get confused who some people are - I am not a clever man.

Comment: @Rick, thanks for pointing that out. I'll add my upvote to that one (and VTC this one).

Comment: Limited to the user and moderators of that site